# Flickr Feeds API Parsing Issues

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization, swifty-json, flickr

I'm facing weird parsing issues where the `Flickr` public feeds API fails to parse with `NSJSONSerialization` `(SwiftyJSON)` about 80% of the time (meaning, it succeeds about 20% of the time).

This is the URL I'm accessing:
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Clearly, this isn't the common `JSONP` issue that many users have faced.

**Things I've tried**:

The error message I get is `"Invalid escape sequence around character ..."`, so I tried going to the exact character number, but I can't find a useful pattern there either.

How do I proceed? I've come across some instances where users have suggested replacing the "`\\'`" character with "`'`", but that doesn't seem to help either.

**Update**

When I added an extra query parameter `lang=en-us`, I get a MUCH better success rate - the response successfully parses about 80% of the time now.

Comment: Do you use `responseJSON` `Alamofire` function?

Comment: Yes, I used that one, and again I had about the same success rate as the `responseString` method of Alamofire.

Comment: Sad, it was my next idea :|

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan, check my update about the `lang=en-us` query param. Surely that must mean something's wrong with the Flickr API response? (bad practices/characters)

Comment: From my experience with one of my past projects, I have had such error with `JSON` response from the server, and if I remember correctly, in my case response contained unexpected `html` tags.